# Connecting 2 phantom device in one copmter

Tags: matlab, driver, phantomjs, simulink

I am working on haptic science.

I need to connect two phantom devices in the same computer. how can I identify the phantom blocks for each device in the same file?

How to identify the phantom block to a certain device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](http://www.quarcservice.com/ReleaseNotes/files/phantom_block.html) is what you are referring to, the answer seems quite simple.

The phantom block contains a parameter `Device Name`.  This parameter should be the name of the device as set up in the Phantom Configuration (outside MATLAB).  So give your two devices different names and then make sure the right name is in the phantom block you are using for each.